# How do I centre the column header in tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

How can I centre the column header, no matter what I try i cant seem to do it[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include your code in your question for us to help better.

There's a property called `headerHozAlign` that you can set to `center`.

Here's how you'd do it:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", headerHozAlign:"center"}, //center align column header title
    ],
});
```